# How to determine server address in ms sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

trying to connect ms sql to vb.net, but I don't know how to determine server address, initial catalog and the user ID

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your admin. Seriously, if you dont know which database to connect and where your server is, you have no business on the server.

if you just dont know how to program, i suggest reading documentation first. Tutorials et al. Trial and error rarely works.